# Static File Routes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. In this app, I need to dynamically generate the sitemap when its requested. I know how to configure routes in general. However, I'm not sure if I can create a route for a specific file. Currently, I have the following in RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Sitemap",
  url: "resources/sitemap.xml",
  defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Sitemap" }
);
```

In my SiteController, I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Sitemap()
{
  // I will build my sitemap.xml file here and return it.
}
```

When I enter /resources/sitmap.xml into the browser's address bar, I noticed that my Sitemap() action never gets tripped. Is it even possible in ASP.NET MVC to setup a route for a specific file? If so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you got to do in some steps -

**Step 1 -** Map the xml extension to take care of by .Net for routing
Add following section in Web.config under `<system.webServer>` -

```
<handlers>
  <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

**Step 2 -** Define your routes and override requests that match an existing file.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Sitemap",
   url: "{site}.xml",
   defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Sitemap", site = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

then **step 3** - Try to access `/SiteMap.xml`, you will get Controller action hit.

Comment: I found that to route to /sitemap for a non existent sitemap.xml file, I didn't need to add the `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` line, and could also set the `HtmlFileHandler` `path` attribute to 'sitemap.xml' rather than *.xml. Not sure if this will be much of an advantage, but just thought I'm mention it. Thanks for the answer though, v useful.