# Is it possible to route only specific static files in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, static-files

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934150/static-file-routes-in-asp-net-mvc) to similar question.

But I don't want to route ALL existing files (`RouteExistingFiles = true`) and then ignore all of the types I do not need.

Can I be more precise with MVC or IIS settings telling it my intentions?

Comment: In "One ASP", there's now [`routes.MapPageRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it the following way:

In RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*route}", new { route = new AnyExistingFileExceptRazorView() });

    ...
}
```

Where `AnyExistingFileExceptRazorView` is a custom route constraint:

```
public class AnyExistingFileExceptRazorView : IRouteConstraint
{

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string filePath = httpContext.Server.MapPath(httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
                                     .ToLower();

        return File.Exists(filePath) 
               && !( filePath.EndsWith(".cshtml") || filePath.EndsWith(".vbhtml"));
    }
}
```

`ToLower()` is called because I'm not sure which case URL has, and I check the endings expecting the lower case.
It's also possible to compare `Path.GetExtension(fielPath) == ".cshtml";`