# ASP.NET MVC5 Customised Inbound Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm "playing" around with custom inbound URL routing and have came across a problem.

When I pass my custom route a URL to examine, that ends in *.+, my class is not fired when i submit the request.

An example URL would be "~/old/windows.html"

When I step through this in the debugger, my RouteBase implementation doesn't fire. If i edit the url that i pass to the constructor of my route to try to match against "~/old/windows", my implemetation is fired as expected.

Again, If i change the url ro examine to "~/old/windows." the problem reoccurs.

My Route Implementation is below :-

```
public class LegacyRoute : RouteBase
    {
        private string[] _urls;

        public LegacyRoute(string[] targetUrls)
        {
            _urls = targetUrls;
        }

        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            RouteData result = null;

            string requestedURL = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

            if (_urls.Contains(requestedURL, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                result.Values.Add("controller", "Legacy");
                result.Values.Add("action","GetLegacyURL");
                result.Values.Add("legacyURL", requestedURL);

            }

            return result;
        }

        public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In the RoutesConfig file I have registered my route like so :-

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

routes.Add(new LegacyRoute(new[]{"~/articles/windows.html","~/old/.Net_1.0_Class_Library"}));
```

Can anyone point out why there is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `.html` extension is not handled by .NET, it is handled by IIS directly. You can override by adding the following section in Web.config under `<system.webServer>` -

```
<handlers>
  <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934150/static-file-routes-in-asp-net-mvc). The above will route EVERY `.html` file request to .NET, you might want to be more specific by providing a more complete path if you don't want your routing to handle every `.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, and I'm sure this will help out a lot of fellow developers.

The problem is with IIS Express that is running via Visual Studio.

There is a module configured in the applicationhost.config called :-

**UrlRoutingModule-4.0**

This is how it looks in file :-

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

You need to set the **preCondition** Parameter to "".

To do this :-

- Run you app via Visual Studio
- Right click on IIS Express in your system tray, select "Show All  Applications"
- Click on the project you wish to edit, then click the config URL.
- Open the file with Visual Studio, Locate the module and ammend.

Hope this helps anyone else, who ran into a similar problem.